# Using addEventListener() with React useReducer() returns multiple keypresses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, calculator, addeventlistener

I am making a calculator with React and wanted to add the functionality for the user to input numbers directly from their keyboard. I used `window.addEventListner()` with `useEffect()` but when ever I press a key one the keyboard I get multiple inputs.

Lets say I pressed "1" once on my keyboard, then I will get "11111111" on the screen and printed to the console.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import { ACTIONS } from "./App";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function DigitButton({ dispatch, digit }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT,
        payload: {
          digit: event.key
        }
      })
    });
  });

  return <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT,
          payload: { digit }
        })
      }}
    >
      {digit}
    </button>
}
```

Comment: Your event is registering multiple times. It should only be called once, and you should also remove this event listener when this component unloads. To achieve this, start by passing an empty array ([]) as the second parameter of the useEffect function. Within this useEffect, return a method that removes the 'keypress' event listener.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You create/add an event listener each time `DigitButton` renders, and never clean any of them up when the component unmounts.

## Solution

Add an empty dependency array to the `useEffect` so the effect runs exactly once, and return a cleanup function to remove the event listener.

Example:

```
export default function DigitButton({ dispatch, digit }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      // Only dispatch event when the correct key is pressed.
      if (event.key === digit) {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT,
          payload: { digit: event.key }
        });
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keypress', handler);

    // return cleanup function to remove listener on unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keypress', handler);
    };
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency, run effect once

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT,
          payload: { digit }
        });
      }}
    >
      {digit}
    </button>
  );
}
```

From here, in non-production builds you'll still see the keypress doubled up because the app is rendered within a `React.StrictMode` component that double-mounts components and runs their mounting `useEffect` hook and the keypress event is still hanging around in the Browser context. If you comment out `React.StrictMode` rendering in `index.js` you'll see the correct expected behavior. This is a non-issue in production builds.

See [StrictMode](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) for more details, specifically [Ensuring reusable state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state).

### Demo

Here's a sandbox demo with the above code suggestion and the `React.StrictMode` component commented out.

[image: Edit using-addeventlistener-with-react-usereducer-returns-multiple-keypresses]

Comment: No it still returns multiple numbers when i press a key, it just wont go into and infinite loop now

Comment: @AkshatSharma Think you could create a running codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Yes I can, wait pls

Comment: here is the link for codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-calculator-use-reducer-pfq297?file=/src/DigitButton.js , the code I posted here is in `src/DigitButton.js`  , `src/App.js` contains the reducer function

Comment: i can't figure out how to edit the previous comment so I am trying to tag u here @DrewReese

Comment: @AkshatSharma Updated answer, please check when you have availability.

Comment: thank you that helps a lot, I was also about to use an array to check if the pressd key is a number but the line you added `if (event.key === digit)`  looks better